# Как установить публичное фото профиля в Pyrogram

Tags: python, telegram, pyrogram

Как установить публичное фото через Pyrogram? Когда скрываешь фотки, появляется пункт установить публичное фото, на скрине видно

[image: Скриншот Пункта]